# Calculating groups in Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a task here I have a data frame containing data about visits in a particular site.
Here's a sample:

| visitsite | userid | timeonsite |
| --- | --- | --- |
| facebook.com | kahy68 | 91973 |
| facebook.com | jjsga12 | 2895 |

I need to create cohorts(groups) based on timeonsite(presented in seconds) column. I need also to calculate how many users are in each cohort and what is their share out of all users.

An output example:

| visitdurationcohort | 1000-2000 | 2000-3000 | 3000-5000 | 5000+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| usersquantity | 1383 | 9973 | 3899 | 684 |
| shareofusers | 7% | 60% | 30% | 3% |

So i found exampkes on how to create cohorts out of a specific value (a month of registartion for example), but not in how to create a range cohort.

I will apreciate any help :)

Comment: You can "bin" your `timeonsite` dimension with `pd.cut`, then do `groupby` over the bins, and either do `count()` on `user_id` for number of users, or `nunique()` on `user_id` for number of unique users. Then you may wrap the result with a `pd.DataFrame` to get a dataframe that contains data of the header and `usersquantity` of your expected output. It's then easy to add another column for `shareofusers` by dividing the `usersquantity` column with the total of it. Finally, do `transpose()` to get what you need. Checkout how to use those methods on pandas documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As per @raymond-kwok:

```
bins = [0,1000,2000, 3000, 5000,10000]
df1 = df.groupby(pd.cut(df["timeonsite"], bins)).count()
df1 = df1[["userid"]]
df1["shareofusers"] = df1["userid"]/(df1["userid"].sum())
df1 = df1.T
```

Comment: it works! Thank you. How can I change the index ‘user’ to be called ‘userquantity’?

Comment: Just use the `rename` API. So just before transposing: `df1 = df1.rename(columns={"userid": "userquantity"})`